# Python auto indents when I copy/paste

Tags: python, indent

I have tried to copy/paste my code into my code editor on my MAC. However, it auto indents everything. Is there a way to un-indent multiple lines at once?

Comment: what is your editor?

Comment: This is not a programming question according to the FAQ. You should ask this on SuperUser (or read the manual of your editor), because it's not Python, it's your editor that does the indenting.

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on what's the editor you are using. If it's vi/vim, just type :set paste before pasting the code.

Comment: I'm using CodeRunner.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python IDLE just `ctrl+H`-> check `Regular expression` ->Enter `^\t` -> `Replace All` .... done :).

Comment: This will mess up indentation everywhere else in the file...

Comment: @TimPietzcker:- This is weird, try using find and it shows starting indents but at replace all its removing everything...some sort of bug...

Comment: Is this IDE the one hat comes with macPython? Right now, I'm using an app called CodeRunner

Answer (score 0):

Try command+[ or command+] after you've selected the lines
That at least works for me in IDLE.

Comment: What is the IDLE? The one that comes with MacPython?

Comment: IDLE is one of the editors. http://www.python.org/getit/

Does that command+[ trick not work in your current editor?

Comment: Hmm, It just worked in my current editor, instead of Ctrl-c I used the copy function on pastebin, but I'm gonna use the other IDLE. Does it come with pygame?